# Can i get the generic type of an object?

Tags: c#, list, generics

this is my method: `GetListItemsPainted<T>(List<T> list)`
and i don't know what type is that list of,

how can i create new list that would have the passed list type?

something like this:

```
List<list.GetType()> newList = new List<list.GetType()>();
```

how can i cast my list to the real type so i would have all his properties etc.?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to create a new List, you already have one.

If you require a specific type, then constrain your generic type parameters with a `where` [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

If you intend to react to a wide variety of arbitrary types, which is a bad design decision in my opinion, then you will need to use a conditional with  `.Cast<T>()`

something like:

```
Type myListType = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
// or Type myListType = typeof(T); as stated by Kobi
if(myListType == typeof(SomeArbitraryType))
{
   var typedList = list.Cast<SomeArbitraryType>();
   // do something interesting with your new typed list.
}
```

But again, I would consider using a constraint.

Comment: @dubi - if it provided the needed guidance you should click on the checkmark.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a list using `T`:

```
List<T> newList = new List<T>();
```

If you must get the type, you can use `typeof`. This is similar to what you asked for, but has other uses, you don't need it to make generics work:

```
Type myType = typeof(T);
```